# While using curl, how to add a subject to the email?

Tags: linux, curl, smtp, gmail

This is he code I am using to send email from my Linux OS to Gmail. It works really well, except the subject is still shown as no subject in my gmail inbox.
[![No Subject in GMAIL[1]][1]

````
curl --ssl-reqd \
--url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' \
--user $EMAIL_SENDING_FROM:$GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD \
--mail-from $EMAIL_SENDING_FROM \
--mail-rcpt $EMAIL_SENDING_TO \
--header "Subject: The files you requested" \
--upload-file $PROCESS_LOG```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/74wLW.png
````

Answer (score 0):

The file $PROCESS_LOG should contain a line at the top with Subject:
For instance:

```
Subject: The file you requested

This is a log
...
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think *--Header* should be replaced with *--data-binary* with data, try:

```
curl --ssl-reqd \
--url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' \
--user $EMAIL_SENDING_FROM:$GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD \
--mail-from $EMAIL_SENDING_FROM \
--mail-rcpt $EMAIL_SENDING_TO \
--data-binary "Subject: The files you requested\n\nThe files you requested are attached." \
--upload-file $PROCESS_LOG
```

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: try: 
````
.. .
--mail-rcpt $EMAIL_SENDING_TO \
-H "Subject: The files you requested" \
--upload-file $PROCESS_LOG
````

Comment: Adding as header with -H does not work!

Answer (score -1):

try
--upload-file "Subject: The files you requested\n $PROCESS_LOG"

Comment: This does not work at all!